# Retrieving arguments of a function call with default values in R

Tags: r, parsing

Is there a way to retrieve function arguments from an evaluated formula that are not specified in the function call?

For example, consider the call `seq(1, 10)`. If I wanted to get the first argument, I could use `quote()` and simply use `quote(seq(1,10))[[1]]`. However, this only works if the argument is defined at the function call (instead of having a default value) and I need to know its exact position.

In this example, is there some way to get the `by` argument from `seq(1, 10)` without a lengthy list of `if` statements to see if it is defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to note is that all of the named arguments you're after (`from`, `to`, `by`, etc.) belong to `seq.default()`, the **method** that is dispatched by your call to `seq()`, and not to `seq()` itself. (`seq()` itself only has one formal, `...`).

From there you can use these two building blocks

```
## (1) Retrieves pairlist of all formals
formals(seq.default)
# [long pairlist object omitted to save space]

## (2) Matches supplied arguments to formals
match.call(definition = seq.default, call = quote(seq.default(1,10)))
# seq.default(from = 1, to = 10)
```

to do something like this:

```
modifyList(formals(seq.default),
           as.list(match.call(seq.default, quote(seq.default(1,10))))[-1])
# $from
# [1] 1
# 
# $to
# [1] 10
# 
# $by
# ((to - from)/(length.out - 1))
# 
# $length.out
# NULL
# 
# $along.with
# NULL
# 
# $...
```